# Error: Maximum update depth exceeded when using react input mask on formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am trying to bind `react-input-mask` with formik. However, I get an error on the first key stroke. Here is how I am trying to use it. If i remove react-input-mask then the code works as a normal textfield but if i use input mask then only i get 'maximum updated depth' error. What might be the reason?

```
const InputMaskField = ({
  label,
  field,
  form,
  prepend,
  append,
  innerAppend,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false)
  const hasError =
    (get(form.touched, `${field.name}`) || get(form, 'submitCount') > 0) &&
    get(form.errors, `${field.name}`)
  return (
    <InputWrapper>
      <Label isActive={active}>{label}</Label>
      <InputMask {...rest}>
        {(inputProps) => {
          return (
            <>
              <TextInputWrapper isActive={active}>
                {prepend && <InputAddonItem prepend>{prepend}</InputAddonItem>}
                <InputAddonField
                  isActive={active}
                  hasError={hasError}
                  prepend={!!prepend}
                  append={!!append}
                  {...field}
                  {...inputProps}
                  onBlur={(e) => {
                    setActive(false)
                    field.onBlur(e)
                  }}
                  onFocus={() => setActive(true)}
                />
                {append && (
                  <InputAddonItem
                    isActive={active}
                    hasError={hasError}
                    {...field}
                    {...rest}
                  >
                    {append}
                  </InputAddonItem>
                )}
                {innerAppend && <InnerAppend>{innerAppend}</InnerAppend>}
              </TextInputWrapper>
            </>
          )
        }}
      </InputMask>
      {hasError && <Error>{hasError}</Error>}
    </InputWrapper>
  )
}
```

Comment: "What might be the reason?" Typically it is unguarded state updates. From what you shared my guess is something is causing the input to lose and regain focus so `active` is continually toggled. Maybe the `isActive` prop of `TextInputWrapper`. Or *some* global form state is rerendering the entire input and triggering the state update looping..

Comment: I already tried removing state to update active flag. I get the same error. No idea about global form state.

Comment: removing field object removes that issue but the form does not work on masking.